# Laravel Sanctum can login in development mode but not in production

Tags: laravel-10, laravel-sanctum, laravel-breeze

I am using Laravel 10 as an API with vuejs 3 as SPA frontend

I use the breeze starter kit for SPA auth with sanctum.

the vue3 SPA is on a **compta.mydomain.fr** sub domain of my shared web hosting
and the laravel app is on a **compta-be.mydomain.fr** sub domain

In development mode everything works smoothly but when I try to login in production mode it fails.
More precisely:

- a first request to '/sanctum/csrf-cookie' succeeds status 204
- a subsequent request to '/login' succeeds status 204

after that I try to get the user

- a new request to '/sanctum/csrf-cookie'  succeeds again Status 204
- but a request to '/api/user' fails: response is message  "Unauthenticated." status 401

Additional info:

- This doesn't happen in development mode
- I can register a user in both    modes (dev and prod)

I am turning mad as when I solve a problem an other arises. This one is the last.

Detailed info

```
async getToken() {
            await axios.get('sanctum/csrf-cookie')
        },
        async fetchUser() {
            await this.getToken()
            const data = await axios.get('/api/user')
            this.authUser = data.data
        },
        async apiLogin(data) {
            console.log('login in store')
            this.authErrors = []
            await this.getToken()
            try {
                await axios.post("/login", {
                    email: data.email,
                    password: data.password
                })
                this.fetchUser()
                
                return true
            } catch (error) {
                if (error.response.status === 422) {
                    this.authErrors = error.response.data.errors
                }
                return false
            }
```

Main instance of axios

```
import axios from "axios";

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.defaults.withXSRFToken = true;
if(process.env.NODE_ENV ==='development'){
    axios.defaults.baseURL="http://localhost:8000";
}
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
    axios.defaults.baseURL="https://compta-be.mydomain.fr";
}

axios.defaults.headers.common['Accept']="application/json";
```

in .env

```
APP_URL=https://compta-be.mydomain.fr
FRONTEND_URL=https://compta.mydomain.fr
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=*.mydomain.fr,https://compta-be.mydomain.fr,https://compta.mydomain.fr
SESSION_DOMAIN=.mydomain.fr
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
```

No change made  to config/session.php, config/sanctum.php, config/cors.php

Comment: Probably I will finish mad! I didn't do anything but while I was asking the same question on another place the problem disappeared! Weird, isn't it?